# Change Vue 'provide' data during test

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils, vue-composition-api

I'm using `vue-test-utils`@1.1.3 with `jest`@26 in order to test my component.

The component gets `provide` data from a parent, and watches for changes of it.
Parent component injects a computed value. I want to check that the watcher (and functionality it invokes) works as expected.

I wonder how can I perform a change of the mocked data I provide in the test?

```js
// ParentComponent.vue, using the @vue/composition-api plugin + syntax
setup() {
  let chosenItems = reactive({ items: [] })
  function UpdateItems(items) {
    chosenItems.items = [...items]
  }
  provide(
    "userItems",
    computed(() => chosenItems.items)
  )
  return { UpdateItems }
}
```

```js
// The component I want to test, using options-api syntax
export default {
  inject: ["userItems"],
  watch: {
    "userItems.value": function (items) {
      // Do Things...
    },
  },
}
```

```js
// The test code for the component
const wrapper = mount(ComponentToTest, {
  localVue,
  router,
  provide: {
    userItems() {
      return ["mockedItems"]
    },
  },
})
// And now, after mounting, I want to change the data was provided to test the watcher
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find another way besides the workaround of calling `wrapper.setData({ userItems: ["mockedNewItems"] })`.

It will work and will trigger the watcher, but it is as if you're mutating the provided data, which is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Why is mutating the provided data a problem? I can copy the original value if needed for other tests, or initialize it in the `beforeEach` function

Comment: Because in a true Vue component, the child component is not supposed to mutate the data that is injected. In the same way that a child component is not supposed to mutate props. If you call setData and run the test, you will see a warning in the terminal of this kind, telling you it's an anti-pattern. That said, it may not be a problem for a test.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, something that takes a bit more work, but doesn't mutate the provided data, would be to extract this part from `ParentComponent.vue`:

```
setup() {
  let chosenItems = reactive({ items: [] })
  function UpdateItems(items) {
    chosenItems.items = [...items]
  }
  provide(
    "userItems",
    computed(() => chosenItems.items)
  )
  return { UpdateItems }
}
```

to a separate function, which provides it (in a separate file):

```
export default function provideChosenItems() {
  let chosenItems = reactive({ items: [] });
  function UpdateItems(items) {
    chosenItems.items = [...items];
  }
  provide(
    "userItems",
    computed(() => chosenItems.items)
  );
  return { UpdateItems };
}
```

Consequently, in your test you can mount the parent component, mock the implementation of the provider function, and then change the data that is provided:

```
import ParentComponent from "ParentComponent.vue";
import provideChosenItems from "provideChosenItems";
import VueCompositionApi, { provide, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import { createLocalVue, mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueCompositionApi);

jest.mock("provideChosenItems");

describe("test", () => {
  it("test", () => {
    const mockedItems = ["mockedItems1"];

    provideChosenItems.mockImplementation(() => {
      provide("userItems", ref(mockedItems));
      return { UpdateItems: () => {} };
    });

    const wrapper = mount(ParentComponent, {
      localVue
    });

    mockedItems.push("mockedItems2");

    // Data is changed, so you can test what happens afterwards,
    // you could do something like
    // wrapper.findComponent(ComponentUnderTest) and assert on stuff
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Not sure if it works on vue2 composition API, but it should work in vue3 with similar syntax.</sub>

The point of the solution is to "provide" the thing that `inject` expected to receive, which is a reactive reference. Otherwise the is nothing reactive to "watch" in component.

```js
it('test provide watch effect', () => {
  const chosenItems = reactive({ items: ["mockItems"] });
  const items = computed(() => chosenItems.items)

  const wrapper = mount(ComponentToTest, {
    localVue,
    router,
    provide: {
      userItems() {
        return items
      },
    },
  })

  // doing stuff and await for mounting

  chosenItems.items = ["mockItems", "mockItems2"]

  // await flushPromise

  should('watch the change of chosenItems')
})
```

Since the new reactive system should live along without Vue, you can directly import `ref`, `reactive`, `computed` outside of a vue project, in your case, the test file.